# How to extract a single field from nmcli output in bash?

Tags: bash, shell

I would like to extract the result of the following command to store it in a variable:

```
nmcli connection show
```

The result extracted should be `ens18`. Instead, it's roughly as follows:

```
NAME  UUID                                 TYPE           DEVICE
ens18 XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX 802-3-ethernet ens18
```

...as shown in the below graphical screenshot:

[image: output]

I tried for a while but cannot figure how to sort this out.

Comment: Screenshots should be avoided wherever possible in favor of copy-and-pasting text (or at least showing *both* a screenshot and a textual representation, as the question is now edited to do) -- whereas [Why not upload images of code when asking questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/14122) on [meta] speaks specifically to code, many of the reasons apply elsewhere as well. Screenshots aren't searchable; they can't be copied-and-pasted for purposes of testing or troubleshooting; one can't reliably detect hidden or lookalike characters in them; etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have only one result, you can simply do:

```
VAR=$(nmcli -g name connection show)
```

If you got more results, you can play with `head` and `tail` commands.

The active one is always the first one, so to get the active one when having more than of one result run:

```
VAR=$(nmcli -g name connection show | head -1)
```

---

- `VAR` is variable name
- `$( ... )` is command substitution.
- using `-g name` gets the value of desired filed.

It means that run the command and put the result in `VAR`.

Answer (score 0):

If the output of the nmcli command is tab-delimited you can do this

with awk:

```
variable=$(nmcli connection show | awk -F'\t' '{print $4}' | tail -1)
```

with cut:

```
variable=$(nmcli connection show | cut -f4 | tail -1)
```

Comment: `nmcli connection show | awk '{ var=$4 } END { print var }'` would avoid needing to start a copy of `tail`, and would also work with spaces rather than tabs only.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, this may help you

```
var=$(nmcli connection show|grep -v NAME| awk -F " " '{print $1}')
```

Regards

Comment: `awk '! /NAME/ { print $1 }'` would avoid the need for a separate `grep`.

Answer (score 0):

It can be easily achieved by using `awk`:

```
var=$(nmcli connection show | awk 'NR==2{print $1}')
echo "$var"
```

Output: ens18

How it works?

1. The pipe operator '|' is used to pass the output of `nmcli connection show` to `awk`.
2. `NR==2` tells `awk` to process the second row of input.
3. `{print $1}` tells `awk` to print the first column of row being processed.